# How to use rpc:pmap correctly?

Tags: erlang, rpc, pmap

I've found in module `rpc` function [pmap](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/rpc.html#pmap-3). And I've stuck when tried to use it.

The first question - does it requires connection with other nodes, or it would performs as `lists:map` if there is no connection to other nodes?

I've tried to execute `pmap` without connection to other nodes, but got exception:

```
7> rpc:pmap( { erlang, '+' }, [], [[1,1],[2,3]] ).          
** exception exit: badrpc
     in function  rpc:check/2 (rpc.erl, line 745)
```

After that - I've launched another local node and connected it with current. But still get the same error.

Please provide me how to use `rpc:pmap` correctly.

Thanks

**P.S.**
Following code works expectedly (returns result 3):

```
70> erlang:apply( erlang, '+', [1,2] ).
3
71> erlang:'+'(1,2).
3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rpc:map({Module, Function},ExtraArgs,List1) evaluates apply(Module, Function, [Elem|ExtraArgs]), for every element Elem in List1, in parallel.

So the right syntax using erlang:'+' is:

> 1> rpc:pmap( { erlang, '+' }, [2], [1,2,3] ).
>
> [3,4,5]
>
> 2>

which evaluates [1+2,2+2,3+2]

the syntax rpc:pmap( { lists, sum }, [], [[1,2],[4,5]] ) will evaluate [1+2,4+5] and return
[3,9]

Pascal

Comment: Thanks for clarification :) I didn't take into account that `[[1,2] | []]` is `[[1,2]]`, and not `[1,2]`.